# invoke only the openie module from corenlp server

Tags: stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server, corenlp-server

I'd like to invoke only the openIE module once coreNLP server is up. I tried this from shell:

```
$ java -mx4g -cp "$HOME/corenlp/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer &
$ java -cp "$CORE/*" -Xmx1g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPClient edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE -file inputfile.txt
```

After a few seconds, logs get freeze and nothing happens. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the StanfordCoreNLPClient, you need to run a pipeline.  You can find full instructions for using the client here:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

For example:

```
java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPClient -cp "*" -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,natlog,openie -file input.txt  -backends localhost:9000
```

Note that the OpenIE extractor requires everything in the pipeline prior to it, so there is not an extra cost to running this part of the pipeline: `tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,natlog`